# Typescript set property value from other properties during initialization for objects read via response of subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, initialization

I have a simple class

```
export class MyObj{
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
}
```

I am reading data into it from backend using `HttpClient`:

```
this.httpClient.get<MyObj[]>(`backendUrl`).subscribe(
  (response: MyObj[]) => {
    //...some code...
  }
);
```

Now I want to have a `prop4` in this class that will get its value from other properties during initialization and will be available in the above `response` array. To achieve this I changed the class code to below but it didn't work. How can I achieve what I want?

```
export class MyObj{
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: string;

  constructor(prop1, prop2, prop3) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    this.prop3 = prop3;
    this.prop4 = prop1 + prop2 + prop3;
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript is erased in compilation, is doesn't exist at run time and **cannot** do any casting or conversion. Just passing a generic type doesn't mean the class gets instantiated (it doesn't). Read https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should declare the raw `ApiResponse` separately from your `MyObj` class:

```
interface ApiResponse {
  prop1: string
  prop2: string
  prop3: string
}

class MyObj {
  prop1: string
  prop2: string
  prop3: string

  // additional props
  prop4: string

  constructor(rawResponse: ApiResponse) {
    this.prop1 = rawResponse.prop1
    this.prop2 = rawResponse.prop2
    this.prop3 = rawResponse.prop3

    // additional props
    this.prop4 = rawResponse.prop1 + rawResponse.prop2 + rawResponse.prop3
  }
}
```

Then do the parsing (maybe some validation) after the API request:

```
get<ApiResponse[]>('https://www.example.com')
  .subscribe((response) => {
    const myObjs = response.map(x => new MyObj(x))

    // do something with myObjs
  })
```

- [Link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgCUIGd0D2IuKA3gFDLLpQHoCMAXMrmFKAOaXW3oBMzVuxBcqNOgGZBbTuQC%205cggA2cXLmQBZAJ4B5AEYArZBTG8mLGSO7j%2004aJ6T7s7gHo3yOABNvwMMBEcMpO6Lg2vAAsLtbcCERCAK4IYARQABRQcADuOPgJEMwY2HiExBAAlCbcVGAAFsC4AHS29MgAvMhZuaUFLeY1yPWN-XR8HV05eWUko-yDw822EhPd033LilRUHl6%20-oEgwaHh20MNS1GrU73lc20A1JM9%20Xe2409rt7ObVAoK5FAkFgiBQAAkwGB0ABhZTACDgapUDgQMAAHgAKgA%20dKJKDKGIcCrMUzbXCJfS4BDsfQQdLkynU4C0qDMTLfQrIDFVdpY5AANwIwG8xIFQu83H%20inixDAyBU8MRnVIci8GghUNhirASjhCLATRR6OK63KAG0ALo4gDkdUhYUYHmyzqaEAAHnAALboZQQJrxT3WircJoMqk0uns14kHl80lUGWsZCevRGDSdKAcpqeuDodJujp8kAQbJaVOGfMVYODXbeAgsAie1ENETIbL%20OrJ8unZByCpAA)

Comment: Yes, this makes more sense. After getting some feedback on the question, I understood that my original class wasn't even being instantiated the way I thought it was.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
Object.assign(this.prop4, this.prop1, this prop2, this.prop3);
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all, `Object.assign` isn't a replacement for adding.